# JavaScript: Taking string from HTML input field to process through an acronym-generating code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a script where string taken from an HTML input field is then processed through an acronym-generating code. Here's what I have:

In HTML file:

```
     <h1>Acronym Creator</h1>
     <p>
        <input type="text" id="phrase" />
        <input type="button" id="clicker" value="Click me!" />
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
<script src="20.js"></script>
```

In JavaScript file:

```
var words = document.getElementById("phrase").value.split(" ");
var acronym = "";
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 1) {
    acronym += words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
}
var report = function() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = acronym;
};
$('#clicker').click(function(){
    var myVar = $('#phrase').val();
alert(myVar);
});
```

How do I get my script to function? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Check that the file url is correct, and make sure you have jquery script also.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, haha; I purposely named the JS file 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the acronym generation code in the click handler

```js
$('#clicker').click(function() {
  var myVar = $('#phrase').val();

  var words = myVar.split(" ");
  var acronym = words.map(function(word) {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  }).join('');
  $("#result").html(acronym);

  console.log(myVar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Acronym Creator</h1>
<p>
  <input type="text" id="phrase" />
  <input type="button" id="clicker" value="Click me!" />
</p>
<p id="result"></p>
```